# Custom directive to validate data after submit in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use a custom directive to validate some data after a call to a web service.
I found an example on blogs, but it calls the web service at every change in the form value!!

I'd like this custom directive to be called only when the user submits data.

Here is the current code:

```
// The directive aims to know if scan.value already exists (HTTP Response 2xx) or not (HTTP 404) in the database.
.directive('ensureExists', ['$http',
                             function($http) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.toto.com/api/' + scope.scan.value
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('exists', true);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('exists', false);
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="number"
    name="cardid"
    required
    ng-model="scan.value"
    ng-focus <!-- Another custom directive that make simple data type validation -->
    ensure-Exists
    />
```

Currently, I have the feeling the code is called as soon as the form is loaded, since I have an error because scope.scan.value is undefined.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The article you looked at intended for proactive validation before you submit, which is why it fires right away. What you are looking for is a directive that waits to do its validation until it is instructed to do so. You could broadcast events from a controller or service and respond to them in your directive, or you simply could just have the directive watch a scope variable on the parent controller until it evaluates to true, then do what you need it to do.

[Here's a very plain example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7uGSYjHDQZbwpF1qAqf5?p=preview) of a directive that waits for a signal from the parent controller.

You could combine that with yours:

```
.directive('ensureExists', ['$http',
                             function($http) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      checkValidity: '&ensureExists',
      scan: '=ensureExistsScan'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
       function check() {
          $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: 'http://www.toto.com/api/' + scope.scan.value
           }).success(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
             ctrl.$setValidity('exists', true);
           }).error(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
             ctrl.$setValidity('exists', false);
           });
       }

       scope.$watch(function() { return scope.checkValidity(); }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
           // only check if the value transitioned from false to true
           if (newValue === true && !oldValue) check();
      });          
    }
  };
}]);
```

Usage in a template (assumes `scan` is a value on the parent controller's scope):

```
<input ... ensure-exists="ccnumberExists" ensure-exists-scan="scan" />
```

Then all you need to do is set the directive attribute to a scope value on your parent controller, like in my first example, and when you want it to kick off the check (such as after you submit something), just set that scope value to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I'm trying to apply it but I face to a `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined` that occurs at the line which contains: `scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.checkValidity(); }`

Comment: typo. should be `scope.checkValidity()`

Comment: Yeah, that's solves the problem thank you. But when I submit data, I still have an error that tells `scope.scan` is undefined :(  (*Cannot read property 'value' of undefined*)

Comment: I missed that. In this case, I've used an isolated scope so as loosely couple your directive from your parent controller, so you can reuse it in other places. If that's not necessary (meaning you only use it in one spot), delete the `scope: { ... },` part and change the watch to whatever the scope value is that you're watching. If you do want to reuse it, you could just add a scope item for scan. I'll update my answer.